# Get cart items in Magento 2.4 blocks

Tags: magento2, cart, blocks, addtocart

I'm trying to get access to all items in the shopping cart in a block, but I can't seem to get them. If I try the code below to construct and `$items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();` then I get an empty array. Plus this is a deprecated model. Also when I try using `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` I get an empty array for `$items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();`.

How are you supposed to get the items in the shopping cart in Magento 2.4?

Older methods don't seem to work

```
public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_cart = $cart;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code and check.

In Magento 2.4, you can use the **`\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart`** block to access the cart items.

You can inject the **`\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart`** block into your custom block's constructor and use it to access the cart items.

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart;

class YourBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        Cart $cart,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCartItems()
    {
        return $this->cart->getItems();
    }
}
```

You can now use the **`getCartItems()`** method in your template file to access the cart items.

In addition to that, you can also use the **`\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`** class to get the cart items,

```
<?php
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class YourBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCartItems()
    {
        return $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    }
}
```

You can now use the **`getCartItems()`** method in your template file to access the cart items.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: the first solution is the only one that gets the cart items outside the checkout page. Second solution only works on the checkout page